# Invoking a callback of another class in python

Tags: python, class, callback

I am at the beginner level in Python. I went through some similar questions asked in this topic.
My requirement is i my class invokes a member of another class passing its callback function. The other class method will invoke the callback at a later time. I wrote a sample code and this seems to work. But, i wasn't sure if this is the right way to do it, especially the way i invoke the CB function. When the callback function is called, i want its context available. In the code below, the values printed seems to match.
If there's something wrong or a better way to achieve the same, will appreciate the response. Here's the sample code, it's not that big.

```
class cb_class():
    def dp_prnt(self, cb_fn, temp_list, key_val):
        print "CB Class called %d" % key_val
        cb_fn(temp_list, 100) #IS this right??
class app_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ii = 8
    def hndlr(self, temp_list, key_val):
        self.key_val = key_val
        cb_class_obj = cb_class()
        cb_class_obj.dp_prnt(self.cb_hndlr, temp_list, key_val)
    def cb_hndlr(self, temp_list, key_val):
        print "CB Called %d"  %key_val
        phy = temp_list.get('phy')
        print "phy %s" % phy
        print "old VAL %d" % temp_list.get('old_val')
        print "ii is %d" % self.ii
        print "keyval is %d" % self.key_val
obj_app = app_class()
lst = {'phy': 'eth3', 'old_val': 23}
obj_app.hndlr(lst, 67)
```

Thanks a lot.
KP

Comment: Consider using more meaningful names, `hndlr` and `dp_prnt` are actually _less_ readable than their full-length counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

The way you did the callback is correct.

Note that calling `obj_app.hndlr(a,b)` is exacly the same as calling `app_class.hndlr( obj_app, a, b)` - and that's what happens internally.

You may want to read [PEP 8](https://duckduckgo.com/l/?kh=-1&uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.python.org%2Fdev%2Fpeps%2Fpep-0008%2F) for a couple of code style guides. Classes should be CamelCase, and you should leave a blank line between functions and classes